# where clause inside a relationships - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 models like this:

WarehousePivotCategory:

```
 id - warehouse_id - warehouse_category_id
```

Warehouse:

```
title
```

WarehouseCategory:

```
 title_en
```

I've created 2 `hasOne` relationships inside `WarehousePivotCategory` and they work fine:

```
  public function Warehouse()
  {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Warehouse','id','warehouse_id');
  }

  public function WarehouseCategory()
  {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\WarehouseCategory','id','warehouse_category_id');
  }
```

in the database I have two records in `warehouses` table :

```
  id title
  1 AA
  2 BB
```

I want to search title in `warehouses` :

```
$title = 'AA';



$warehouses = WarehousePivotCategory::with(['warehouse' => function($q) use ($title) {
    $q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%');
},'WarehouseCategory'])->get();


    foreach ($warehouses as $w)
    {
        echo $w->warehouse->title; // no thing

    }
```

but it doesn't return any of `title` of warehouses.

my relationships is correct because below code works fine :

```
WarehousePivotCategory::with('warehouse','WarehouseCategory')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: in the relationship, hasOne have 2nd param as foreign_key and 3rd param as local_key. I think you miss placed them. Please verify with documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: try this, in the where query change the field name as titles. then it throw an error of whole sql query. In it try can you find something is okay or not. can you understand me..?   and also try ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing get method in your closure. Try it like this:

```
$warehouses = WarehousePivotCategory::with(['warehouse' => function($q) use ($title) {
$q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')->get(); },'WarehouseCategory'])->get();
```

You can also send array of fields you want to fetch to get method, like this:

```
    $warehouses = WarehousePivotCategory::with(['warehouse' => function($q) use ($title) {
$q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')->get(['id', 'title']); },'WarehouseCategory'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong. You don't need to use hasone while you have created pivot.You need to use BelongsToMany

```
class warehouse extends Model{

   public function ware_cat(){
       return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\WarehouseCategory');
   }
   public function getWarehouse(){
       $this->with('ware_cat')->get();
   }
}
```

Pivot table will fetch it so in warehouse model you will get its category and in category model you will get the warehouse same way visa-versa.