# Laravel relationship where clause returns all records parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-models

I have three tables, File, FileFolder and Folder. These tables all have their own Laravel Model, with their respective names.

**File**
[image]

**FileFolder**
[image]

**Folder**
[image]

Now, I need to retrieve all files that are in `folder 1`. Our project already contains an Eloquent relationship within the `File model`, which looks like this:

```
    public function folderRelation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FolderFileRelation::class, 'FileId', 'FileId');
    }
```

Looking at the official [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) and these questions on stackoverflow:

[where clause inside a relationships - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999627/where-clause-inside-a-relationships-laravel)

[Laravel query relationship where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316848/laravel-query-relationship-where-clause)

[Laravel relationship where clause is returning records outside relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71844449/laravel-relationship-where-clause-is-returning-records-outside-relationship)

[WHERE clause with relationship to another table in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973081/where-clause-with-relationship-to-another-table-in-laravel)

It clearly states, that for my use case, I need to use the standard `with` function, to include my relationship, so I can use a where clause on my `FileFolder` model.

My code now looks like this:

```
        $files = File::with(['folderRelation' => function($query) {
                $query->where('FolderId', 1); 
        }])->get();
```

**Expected outcome**
The where-clause on my `FileFolder relationship` is used, and only the contents from the File table, where the File is in folder 1 get queried from the database.

**Returned in $files**
[image]

**Actual outcome**
The where-clause on my `FileFolder relationship` is not used, and all the contents within the File table get queried from the database.

**Returned in $files**
[image]

Did I implement my query correctly, or is it better to use a raw-query in this use case?

**Possible solutions**

*Raw query*

Using a raw-query, which would work exactly as I'd want it too. The biggest downside to this method is not being able to use the collections as needed.

*Querying folder, then retrieving files*

I could query like this:

```
   $files = FileFolder::where('FolderId', $folder)->get()->files();
```

But, one of my requirements is querying only "image" files, looping over all the files, and dropping keys that are not images, would create an unnecessary extra loop, which would eat away server resources when deployed to production.

(sidenote, sorry for adding the tables as images. I made them with the MD-editor, but couldn't seem to post them due to stackoverflow incorrectly identifying them as code, treating them as inline-code as stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404314/a-markdown-table-is-detected-incorrectly-as-a-badly-formatted-code-block) does not seem to work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for more detail on the difference between `whereHas` and `with` [Laravel: Difference between whereHas and with contains constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425194/laravel-difference-between-wherehas-and-with-contains-constraint/71425457#71425457)

The right code would be the following

```
$files = File::with(['folderRelation'])->whereHas('folderRelation', function ($query) {
    $query->where('FolderId', 0); 
})->get();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you for linking me the article, it explains it a lot better than the official documentation.